# RabbitMQ slow consumers

Tags: rabbitmq

I did a base install of RabbitMQ, the latest, without any configuration changes.  It is running, and I have 2 million messages sitting on a queue, but I'm only able to pull them off 20 at a time.  I was expecting in the thousands.  I haven't been able to find anything obvious in the configuration documentation that says explicitly configure this for a high-throughput production environment.  Could someone push me in the right direction to figure out why I'm not getting any throughput?  I have 1 consumer with a prefetch count of 24.  The consumer does nothing with the message, just pulling it off for testing purposes.

I have a base rabbitmq.config file, which only contains this:

```
[
  {rabbit, [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.7}]}
].
```

I have looked through the example config at https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/docs/rabbitmq.config.example but nothing stands out as something that needs to be configured in order to speed up the consumers.

Comment: You can ensure it's not network or configuration related using [rabbitmq-perf-test](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test) (results will be much higher from what you can expect in practice, but on my local machine, it's around 40000m/s, very far from what you get). Actions you should take will highly depend if the issue comes from your cluster configuration or from your app. To improve throughput, ack messages in bulk using the `multiple` flag, or just disable acknowledgements at least for debugging.

Comment: Also, it might sound obvious but since you didn't precise, let's try: use basic consume rather than " while get" and ensure your messages content is not too large.

Comment: What do you mean by "pull them off 20 at a time"? By default, a consumer will retrieve all messages in a queue into its buffer in order to process them faster. You can change this by playing with the prefetch counts.

Comment: The comment about checking your environment using PerfTest is a great suggestion. This is almost certainly due to the code you are using to consume messages. Without seeing that, we can only make guesses here.

If you would like more help, I suggest posting this question to the rabbitmq-users mailing list along with more information about your environment as well as code that can be used to reproduce what you are seeing.